# Windows 2012 Master & Ubuntu Bind 9 Slave & SOA

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, bind, soa-record

I'm kinda like the maid... I don't do Windows.  But thanks to new things we're implementing, I'm now attempting replicating a single zone from our AD cluster.  We had this working just fine but someone had to "adjust" it.  That broke the replication completely.  We've gotten that restarted but now a different DC is showing as the SOA.

Does it matter which of the domain controllers is listed as the SOA?  The contents of the zone file appear to be correct.  Part of me says "Good enough.  Leave it be." but the rest of me doesn't want a 3AM phone call.  So does anyone know if it matters which DC is listed as the SOA?

Comment: Are the zones AD integrated?

Comment: Yes, the AD zones are integrated.

Comment: Then it doesn't matter. Each DC is the SOA for it's copy of the zone. If you look at the properties of the zone from each DC you should see that each DC is the SOA for its copy of the zone.

Comment: Yay!  Thanks!  Windows is weird and confusing :)  Just wanted to be sure it wasn't still broken.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this question but who is not using AD-integrated zones, the SOA needs to be the server which hosts the zone file. Because as @joeqwerty pointed out in an AD-integrated DNS environment, the DNS zones are integrated with AD (and consequently part of AD replication) each DC is the SOA of its copy of the zone file.